# Why does localizedDescription of NSError say Optional("description")?

Tags: string, swift, option-type, nserror

Whenever I do `println(error.localizedDescription)` I get something that says :

> Optional("description of the error here")

Rather than just:

> "description of the error here"

How do I get rid of the `Optional()` part of the description?

I tried the below method which results in a compiler error saying that it's not an optional.

```
func performLoginRequestWithURL(url: NSURL, email: String, password: String) {
        let bodyData = "email=\(email)&password=\(password)"
        var request: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.HTTPBody = bodyData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()){
            response, data, error in

            if let error = error {
               let errString = error.localizedDescription
               NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(self.lh, object: nil, userInfo: ["Result": errString])

            } else if data != nil {
                let json = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String

                if let dictionary = JSON().parseJSON(json) as [String: AnyObject]? {
                    let accesstoken = dictionary["id"] as! String
                    let id = dictionary["userId"] as! Int
                    var results = [String: AnyObject]()
                    results = ["at": accesstoken, "id": id]

                    // MARK: - Store UID & AccessToken
                    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "userLoggedIn")
                    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(id, forKey: "userId")
                    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(accesstoken, forKey: "accessToken")
                    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
                    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(self.lh, object: nil, userInfo: ["Result": "Success"])
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is correct - error is an optional but error.localizedDescription is not. You either need to unwrap the error first, safely by

```
if let unwrappedError = error {
     println(unwrappedError.localizedDescription)
}
```

or: Use optional chaining - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html

```
let description = error?.localizedDescription
```

which will either cause 'description' to be the string of localizedDescription, if the error optional can be unwrapped successfully, or possibly 'nil' if not.

Code taken from example added to question. Seems to work as ok, below code can be copied into playground to show error and data string printout - just add valid http:// address into see valid return or try with just 'http:' to get an error.

```
import UIKit
import XCPlayground

func performLoginRequestWithURL(url: NSURL) {
    let request: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()){
        response, data, error in

        if let error = error {

            let errString = error.localizedDescription

            print(errString)

        } else if data != nil {

            let json = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String

            print(json)
        }
    }
}

performLoginRequestWithURL(NSURL(string:"http:")!)

XCPSetExecutionShouldContinueIndefinitely()
```

Comment: I already tried that part as well using if let error = error { ... } (see above). It's how it is right now, that's where error in error.localizedDescription comes from.

Comment: Which class is this NSError being generated from?

Comment: From NSURLConnection, it's a POST request to a remote server.

Comment: Can you add a full code block with as much as possible to your question - blank out http address,exact info being sent etc, if necessary, so investigation into specific issue possible?

Comment: Sorry, all seems ok here, I have added code to answer to copy and paste into a playground to show non optional error.localizedDesciption

Comment: Strange, I have it just like you have it above and it still says Optional(The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)) Instead of just "The operation couldn't be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012)" without the word Optional and parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

You have to unwrap `error` using `?`:

```
if let errString = error?.localizedDescription { 
  println(errString) 
}
```

If you already know from an earlier check that `error` isn't `nil`, you can force unwrap:

```
println(error!.localizedDescription)
```

This will crash if `error` is `nil`, so use the `!` syntax with caution.

Comment: I've got it inside a check to see if error isn't nil, but yet it still insists it isn't an optional. So those two options aren't working. Error says that operand should be of optional type.

Comment: I'm using the latest, 6.4